# NLog Hebrew logs look like gibberish

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nlog, hebrew

Im trying to log Hebrew text using NLog but it looks like gibberish.

The NLog configuration is defined from the code (using the LoggerConfiguration class) and the encoding for both the colored console and file targets is utf-8.

There is a difference between how the text is presented between the two targets:

- The console looks like this: îåøùú
- The file target looks like this: \u05de\u05d7\u05d1

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you show your nlog.config? What happens if you use Notepad++ to view the file and specify the contents UTF8? Think that NLog doesn't write a BOM - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/26

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am already viewing the file on notepad++ encoded in it'd-8

Comment: Are you using a JsonLayout in your File-target? Upgrade to NLog to ver. 4.4.7 (or newer) and set escapeUnicode="true" for the message-attribute.

Comment: I am for the file log, but the console is a regular layout and it's still gibberish.

Comment: But I will upgrade it and see how it goes

Comment: The console-target has an encoding-parameter. You can try and use an encoding that works with hebrew: encoding="Windows-1255"

Comment: Usually when I need Hebrew I use utf-8. Can you explain why it would be any different when using nlog

Comment: You can also try UTF-8 for the console-encoding. I have very little experience with non-ascii encoding. Just wanted to give you ideas to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

Add encoding attribute for target element and set it value to utf-8 :

```
 <target name="ownFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="E:\Logs\MyLogLog_${shortdate}.txt" encoding="utf-8" />
```